# why mybatis insert not return last insert id?

Tags: mybatis

I am using mybatis to insert record like this:

```
    @Override
    public void lockRecordHostory(OperateInfo operateInfo) {
        WalletLockedRecordHistory lockedRecordHistory = new WalletLockedRecordHistory();
        JSONObject jsonObject = JSON.parseObject(operateInfo.getParam(), JSONObject.class);
        lockedRecordHistory.setParam(operateInfo.getParam());
        int result = lockedRecordHistoryMapper.insertSelective(lockedRecordHistory);
        log.info("result:", result);
    }
```

why the the result value aways 1 not the last insert id?I turn on debug info of mybatis,and it execute log:

```
DEBUG [http-nio-11002-exec-7] - JDBC Connection [com.alibaba.druid.proxy.jdbc.ConnectionProxyImpl@33d1051f] will be managed by Spring
DEBUG [http-nio-11002-exec-7] - ==>  Preparing: insert into wallet_locked_record_history ( locked_amount, created_time, updated_time, user_id, locked_type, operate_type, param ) values ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ) 
DEBUG [http-nio-11002-exec-7] - ==> Parameters: 1(Integer), 1566978734712(Long), 1566978734712(Long), 3114(Long), RED_ENVELOPE_BUMPED_LOCK(String), LOCKED(String), {"amount":1,"lockedType":"RED_ENVELOPE_BUMPED_LOCK","userId":3114}(String)
DEBUG [http-nio-11002-exec-7] - <==    Updates: 1
DEBUG [http-nio-11002-exec-7] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() 
DEBUG [http-nio-11002-exec-7] - ==> Parameters: 
DEBUG [http-nio-11002-exec-7] - <==      Total: 1
DEBUG [http-nio-11002-exec-7] - Releasing transactional SqlSession [org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession@420ad884]
```

Is the transaction affect the results?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the query that retrieves the value of the generated id uses the separate connection to mysql.

This is from mysql [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) for `LAST_INSERT_ID` function:

> The ID that was generated is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. This means that the value returned by the function to a given client is the first AUTO_INCREMENT value generated for most recent statement affecting an AUTO_INCREMENT column by that client

You are using connection pool and depending on its configuration it might happen that different queries are executed using different native JDBC `Connection` objects, that is using different connections to mysql. So the second query returns the value that was generated (at some earlier time) for the wrong connection from the pool.

To overcome this you do need to configure connection pool so that it does not release the connection after the each statement. You need to configure it so that the pool uses the same connection until the proxy connection is released by you code (that is when mybatis closes connection in the end of the transaction).